# Помогите расставить знаки препинания (2)

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите расставить знаки препинания в следующем предложениии:

**Друзья нужна ваша помощь Какой перевод стиха звучит лучше**

Comment: А где же перевод?

Comment: Мне нужно расставить знаки в этом предложении

Comment: «Нужна ваша помощь Какой...» Какой — это имя?

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, здесь два предложения:

**Друзья, нужна ваша помощь. Какой перевод стиха звучит лучше?**